# How do I add interop assembly that changes its version number?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2008, versioning

My C# program uses a COM component via an interop assembly. The COM component sometimes changes (methods are added at the end of interface). [I need to build this program in an automated build and have the interop assembly incrementing its version number](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4430016/57428) - this can be achieved by using tlbimp as a pre-build step.

The problem is that the reference in the project file is set to some specific version (say 4.0.0.34) - the one which the interop assembly had when the reference was added. Once the number is incremented by an automated build and the pre-build step is done the version number store in the project file no longer matches the number in the assembly properties and I get

> warning MSB3245: Could not resolve this reference. Could not locate the assembly "Interop.MyCOMComponent, Culture=neutral, Version=4.0.0.34, processorArchitecture=MSIL". Check to make sure the assembly exists on disk. If this reference is required by your code, you may get compilation errors.

and then

> The type or namespace name 'MyCOMComponent' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Can I somehow tell Visual Studio that I don't want to store the exact assembly version inside the project file and it should use whatever version it sees at compile time?

Comment: Close your old question(s) first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing that worked for me was to remove the "COM" reference and add the reference to the interop assembly as if it was a normal ".NET" reference. Since the latter doesn't store a version number the problem got solved once and for all.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that in the .csproj file you will find an attribute called `SpecificVersion`, in the `Reference` element.

Removing this attribute may have the effect that you seek.